# Synapse serverless pool to query delta table previous versions

Tags: azure-databricks, azure-synapse, delta-lake

Can we use Synapse serverless pool (Built-in) to query a delta file's previous version?

I am keen to a SQL statement similar to what we do in Databricks:

```
select * from delta.`/my_dir` version as of 2
```

Does the OPENROWSET support support a "version selection" option?

If not possible, does registering the delta table to an external managed table helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I try to query delta table in serverless sql pool in synapse using below code:

```
select * from delta.original version  as  of  0
```

I got below output:

[image]

As per [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/resources-self-help-sql-on-demand?tabs=x80070002#delta-lake)

```
Serverless SQL pools don't support time travel queries.
```

AFAIK with SQL commands are not supported to time travel with Delta Lake. But you can use spark pool loading the data into a dataframe with PySpark.
I used below code to load data to data frame:

```
df = spark.read.format("delta").option("versionAsOf",0)

.load("<file location>")
```

[image]

I displayed the data frame using below code:

```
df.show()
```

[image]

You can try in this way to query with delta table.

Comment: Thank you! Sad to hear it's an absolutely NO from serverless pool.